# My mouse sometimes move without reason. Could it be a virus persisting Ubuntu reinstalls?

Tags: virus, ubuntu, bios

I am running Ubuntu Linux and I have reinstalled the system several times but sometimes I still feel like somebody gets remote access to my computer.

I'm not running any software like Team Viewer.
I did not allow the remote access in options in Ubuntu.
I have completly erased the HDDs and installed pure Ubuntu.

I know that there are some bios viruses in the world but is it possible that the virus would live in an area that is not in touch with OS and after the new OS installation it would infect the system and grant an remote access to the hacker to my computer?

Nothing special has happened but sometimes I recognized that my mouse moved without a reason and since I'm very "paranoid" I would like to make sure myself. Is there any way of scanning the BIOS for viruses?

Comment: Are you on a laptop? Maybe your touch pad is just a bit trigger happy. While some viruses could survive even if you format your HDD, the mouse mysteriously moving *is not a sign you got one*. You are just being paranoid.

Comment: yes im using lenovo laptop

Comment: A friend of mine has a Lenovo, and her touch pad can sometimes fire even when her fingers are not near it. That is probably what is happening to you. Assuming advanced viruses in a situation like this is not reasonable.

Comment: Bad mouse driver, noisy touchpad electronics... We had one that did a little diagonal dance across the screen. Easiest way to fix it was to plug in the real thing and use that instead. Security answer because the issue caused us to take action, It survived a complete drive wipe and OS reinstall, causing pain for the original owner and no fix for the issue.

Comment: i had a touchscreen laptop that would randomly click like crazy when it got humid. it managed to drag my music collection into a few artist folders, making me think my HD was dying or the RIAA hacked me. Unless it's clicking trough apps, i wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Malware advanced enough to persist OS reinstalls would definitely be advanced enough to not give its presence away by moving the cursor.

Comment: Some old dell laptops had a problem like this; the cursor would go off to one corner of the screen randomly. It was due to a damaged & not correctly shielded internal cable. I _very much_ doubt that it's a virus / malware.

Comment: if someone had the capability to put a virus in your BIOS, do you really think  they would give it away by making the mouse move erratically?

Answer (score 4):

Best guess is one or more of the following:

- touch pad picking up (electrical) noise
- mouse is picking up vibrations (most likely a fan)
- faulty drivers causing input when there is none

You could try disabling your touch-pad (physically if necessary) and using a different mouse.